# How to load data from a .txt file into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, text-files

I am trying to fill a textarea with the data from a .txt file.  I have tried using answers from similar questions but I can't find one that works.
In the head of the file I have this to import a library that is used with the jQuery:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Textarea declaration:

```
<textarea id="fillText" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

This is the script tag that I have right after the textarea declaration:

```
<script>
var fileName = '<?php echo $fileN;?>.txt'; //gets the filename
//The follow works and alerts the browser with the contents of the text file
jQuery.get(fileName, function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('fillText').html(data.replace('n',''));

});
</script>
```

I have tried using this also:

```
 $(".fillText").load(fileName);
```

But that does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with a `textarea`, you need to specify the value rather than the html.

Change:

`$('fillText').html(data.replace('n',''));`

To:

`$('#fillText').val(data.replace('n',''));`

Comment: the only issue actually was the #.... `.html` works too. here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/4ot9sqzc/

Answer (score 2):

`.fillText` means you want to look for an HTML element where `class="fillText"`
`#fillText` means you want to look for an HTML element where `id="fillText"`, which is what you seem to want.

you may wanna go though this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Also you can use the load function you showed with `#` since it is meant for exactly this.

Comment: `.load()` can't be used for this, because changing a `textarea` requires writing to the value, not the HTML.

Comment: he does have .fillText in the line of code he has shown `$(".fillText").load(fileName);`

Also text doesn't need writing to the value, that would be an input. I have tested load with textarea